# How to resolve this error in DirectAdmin

Tags: php, cron, jobs, directadmin

I am using cron jobs in DirectAdmin, but I encountered this error:

> Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so: undefined symbol: php_body_write

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a version of ioncube that doesn't match your php version. Connect to your server using SSH and run this:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build clean
./build set ioncube yes
./build ioncube
service httpd restart
```